# C++ : Accessing private member of base or global variable from a derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, c++11

In the following code snippet `check()` is not able to access either variables named `test`:

```
int test; //global variable
class Base {
private:
    int test; //private member of Base
public: 
    void getit() {
         cin>>test;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    void check(){ 
        test ++; //Increments neither global variable nor private member of Base
    }
}
```

What about scopes am I missing here? Shouldn't atleast the global variable be accessible for `check()` ?

Comment: In the scope of `check`, `test` with no prefix refers to `Base::test`, which you can't access because it is private. If you want to increment the global variable, use `::test` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visibility and access checking are independent, meaning that private names are not "invisible" and they are still found by name lookup, even if using them gives an error.

Name lookup in a class scope will look in its own scope first, then look in base classes, then look in enclosing scopes such as the surrounding namespace scope. So in the derived class the unqualified name `test` is looked up and finds `Base::test`, then *after* name lookup has found it access checking is performed, and the entity that was found is private so you get an error.

To refer to a different `test` you need to qualify it, so the global `test` would be referred to as `::test`

Answer (score 1):

private is private. A derived class can't access the private attributes of its base class.

If you want to access `test` from a derived class, you need to declare it `protected`.